# JavaScript function and DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I write function for manipulation with DOM objects. This function must find element with specific ID and add new child element to element with specific ID:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Text </title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body id="tbody">
  <script>
    function add(){
       el = document.getElementById("testform");
       var nf=document.createElement("input");
       nf.type="text";
       el.appendChild(nf);
    }
  </script>

   <p>
     <form id="testform">
       <button onclick="add();"> create</button>
      </form>
   </p>


</body>
</html>
```

Element of text input doesn't create on page,but same code is placed in script tag without function-work

Comment: I think this problem related with local\global variable in JS function and scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reloading the page, and need to return false when clicking the button to stop the form from being submitted :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Text </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body id="tbody">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function add(){
                el = document.getElementById("testform");
                var nf=document.createElement("input");
                nf.type="text";
                el.appendChild(nf);
            }
       </script>
       <p>
       <form id="testform">
           <button onclick="add();return false;"> create</button>
       </form>
       </p>
   </body>
</html>​
```

Also, sticking a form inside a paragraph seems unnecessary ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TNpty/)

Comment: +1 The page is reloading because the default `type` of the `<button >` element is `submit`.

Comment: Thanks for adeneo and Matt

Answer (score 1):

Since the Default action of button element type is submit so it submits every time you click. You can do a return false or create a label tag instead of button something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Text </title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body id="tbody">
    <script>
    function add(){
        el = document.getElementById("testform");
        var nf=document.createElement("input");
        nf.type="text";
        el.appendChild(nf);
    }
    </script>

   <p>
   <form id="testform">
   <label onclick="add();"> create</label>
   </form>
   </p>


   </body>
   </html>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/TNpty/8/)